# Removing the --downlevelIteration error from VS Code

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, generator, tslint

I have a TypeScript project. I've created a generator function, and am iterating over its generated items with

```
for (let item of generator()) { ... }
```

VS Code immediately complained that I needed to add `--downlevelIteration` to my tsconfig.json (without it, `tsc` can't create the right iteration code). So I've added the flag, and indeed - the code compiles and runs properly.

Unfortunately, VS Code is still complaining about this line, marking the for loop with a squiggly red line. This is irritating. There is no apparent `tslint` flag for this. Adding `/* tslint:disable */` before the loop does not make any difference.

How can I make this error go away?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`tslint:disable` refers to [TSLint](https://github.com/palantir/tslint), which is not the same as TypeScript. TSLint is a separate library that adds extra static analysis ("linting") onto TypeScript code. Put another way, TSLint is to TypeScript as ESLint is to JavaScript.

The "disable" flag you're looking for is likely [`@ts-ignore`](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What%27s-new-in-TypeScript#suppress-errors-in-ts-files-using--ts-ignore-comments). But - it's generally bad practice to use that, as it disables *all* TypeScript complaints.

Have you tried restarting VS Code? Maybe it hasn't picked up on the changes?

If that doesn't do it, perhaps your TS config file isn't named `tsconfig.json`? VS Code will only recognize `tsconfig.json` files within your project.

Comment: I have restarted VS Code. My tsconfig.json is called tsconfig.json. It was created by the Angular CLI.

Comment: Anyway, placing @ts-ignore above the problematic line solved the squiggly read line, which is what I wanted in the first place. I agree it's not ideal, but I'd much rather not be distracted by non-errors.

Comment: The restarting of my code editor (WebStorm) did it for me